# managing processes and folder selection on a server from multiple users with SQL

Tags: c#, sql

I apologize if the question sounds ambiguous, wasn't sure how to word it.

I have a Winform app that is installed on five different PC's all connected in a LAN. In the server SQL database, I have a table that holds the names of folders on the server and one of the columns in that table holds a flag for unprocessed/processed.

my app starts by giving the user a list of all the unprocessed folders in that table and the user selects one of those folders and starts doing the process work on that folder, once he is done, the software will change the field in the table from unprocessed to processed.

My problem is, the process can take a while, how do I prevent a second (or more) user/s from selecting the same folder to process.

I've thought of having a third state in the flag = "in process" but then how will this flag reset in the case of a power failure while a user was processing?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to cover the disaster situation, you may want to consider implementing your "in process" flag and also have a file local to your winforms application that records your last action. e.g.

Row is updated with in process = true.
You save to your local config file or text file - current action = processing row with ID ...

If the power fails, have the app check the local file on startup - retrieve the row from the db and carry on.

Or store who is doing what to which row on another table in the db. Then you have a central record.

There may be a way to lock the row in sql and cancel the lock if the connection drops, but you will have to do some googling on that.

Comment: I'm currently working on storing 'who' is accessing that row from the DB like you suggested.